# How to send POST with multiple params in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, http

I want to send multiple parameters using angularjs HTTP post service.
This is my function to send post using in my project

```
function getListObject(table,language) {
var url=API_URL+table+"?";
var companyTemp={company_id:40743};
var languageTemp={language_id:language}   
var cm = "list";
var dtJSON =  JSON.stringify({table: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()),company:JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(companyTemp)),languages: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(languageTemp))});
var data = $.param({
  cm: cm,
  dt: dtJSON
});
return $http.post(url+data).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error get  list'));}
```

Example my url is: **localhost:8080/api/product?cm=list&dt={product:{},company:{company_id:40743},languages:{language_id:"en"}}**

When I use above function, I write: **Service.getListObject("products","en")**.
I have a problem in this line:

```
var dtJSON =  JSON.stringify({table: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(companyTemp)),languages: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(languageTemp))});
```

I want result dtJSON this line is:

```
"{"products":{},"company":{"company_id":40743},"languages":{"language_id":"en"}}"
```

But I receive this :

```
"{"table":{},"company":{"company_id":40743},"languages":{"language_id":"en"}}"
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Remove all JSON.stringify and JSON.parse. $http service does that for you

Comment: @MarcusH Can give me an example?I don't understand to do that when remove all JSON.stringify and JSON.parse.  I want using this function in my project for another urls.
Example:
Service.getListObject("bills","en")
Service.getListObject("report","en")

Answer (score 0):

Documentation : [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http.post(url, data, config);
```

`$http` will handle itself the JSON parsing thus you do not need to do it yourself

```
function getListObject(table, language) {
    var url = API_URL;
    return $http.post(url , {company_id : 40743, language_id : language, cm : "list"});
}
```

Comment: so if i have an url:

Comment: so if i have an url:
localhost:8080/api/booking_bills?cm=list&dt={company:{company_id:40743},"booking_bills":{},"page":{"page_size":20,"page_index":1},languages:{language_id:"en"}}.
How to do it with $http.post?

Comment: Do you need to use query param ?

Comment: or in booking_bills have an param:
localhost:8080/api/booking_bills?cm=list&dt={company:{compan‌​y_id:40743},"booking‌​_bills":{"booking_from_date":"2016-05-26","booking_to_date":"2016-10-26"},"page":{"‌​page_size":20,"page_‌​index":1},languages:‌​{language_id:"en"}}

Comment: Again.. Do you need to use query param ? Can't you just send a json formatted object ?

Comment: yes , i need using some params in another function like above function.

Comment: Because, i have some api need using params in that.

Comment: Example this api search booking bills
localhost:8080/api/booking_bills?cm=search&dt={company:{compan‌​‌​y_id:40743},"booki‌​ng‌​_bills":{"bookin‌​g_from_date":"2016-0‌​5-26","booking_to_da‌​te":"2016-10-26"},languages:‌​{langua‌​ge_id:"en"}}

Comment: Stop posting those urls please. Do you have any controls on the API ? This is an ugly practice

Comment: Sorry. Because i don't know how to push params to http.post. Can you give me an example to push params .